# Difference between get() and onSnapshot() in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am reading some data from Firebase's Cloud Firestore but I've seen several ways to do it. The example I saw used the get and onSnapshot function like this:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
 .onSnapshot(doc => {
      console.log(doc.data());
 });
```

or this

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
         console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
         console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
   console.log("Error getting document:", error);
        });
```

Is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data):

> There are **two ways** to retrieve data stored in Cloud Firestore. Either
> of these methods can be used with documents, collections of documents,
> or the results of queries:
>
> - Call a method to get the data.
> - Set a listener to receive data-change events.
>
> When you set a listener, Cloud Firestore sends your listener an
> initial snapshot of the data, and then another snapshot each time the
> document changes.

When you use `get()` you "retrieve the content of a single document" **only once**. It's a kind of "get and forget": If the document changes in the (back-end) Firestore database you will need to call `get()` again to see the change.

**On the opposite**, if you use the `onSnapshot()` method you *constantly listen* to a document as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen):

> You can listen to a document with the `onSnapshot()` method. An initial
> call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot
> immediately with the current contents of the single document. Then,
> **each time the contents change**, another call updates the document
> snapshot.

As explained in these docs, these two methods apply to one document or to a collection of documents (including a [query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)).

Comment: Is onSnapshot more expensive than get?

Comment: @KickButtowski Yes.

Comment: @KickButtowski You are still only charged per read operations as if you are doing a get method. So in fact, it depends how many CRUD's you are doing ... firebase itself recommends using onSnapshot as a default