# Get document method for Firestore throwing unmounted warning

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a React.js project using Firestore, and I've noticed that when I use the `get` method for documents, I get the "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component" warning. If I use the `onSnapshot` method and unsubscribe it in the `componentWillUnmount` React method, the warning disappears, which makes sense. Why is the `get` method throwing this error? I don't always want to be listening for documents, so I am just wondering the best way to be going about this. Thanks!

**Throws no warning:**

```
  componentDidMount() {

      this.unsubscribeUsers = firestore.collection("users").doc(this.props.user.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        this.setState({
          firstName: doc.data().firstName,
        })
      });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if(this.unsubscribeUsers){
      this.unsubscribeUsers();
    }
  }
```

**Throws warning:**

```
  componentDidMount() {
      firestore.collection("users").doc(this.props.user.uid).get().then((doc) => {
        if (doc.exists) {
          this.setState({
            firstName: doc.data().firstName,
          })
        } else {
            // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
            console.log("No such document!");
        }
      }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }
```

**Full error:**

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Did you find the solution? I am also getting same issue in get() method. I wonder if there is any unsubsribe method for get()

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be on how both methods works. As explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480212/12265927), the `get()` method takes the data only once while the `onSnapshot()` continues listening on the `doc`. The warning is related that you will not have updates on the component (the `doc`) because how `get()` works.