# Flutter and Firebase: Basic structure issues

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Having some issues with understanding how I am supposed to use Firebase, in a logical, structural sense.

I have a database that at present looks like this:

[image]

In the app I have used:

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    <code here>
   }
 ),
```

As all the documentation and guides suggest.

But this returns cycles through all of my documents, which is all my user IDs.   I don't want this as a user should only be seeing their own data.    But if I try and change it to:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).snapshots(),
```

Then is gives an error, because you can only cycle through collections of documents, and not documents of collections.

So then because this design doesn't work at all, I thought maybe adding another superfluous level to the database, to make it like:

```
Collection:
  - application name
  Document: 
    - Stores
      Collection:
         - UID of user
           Fields:
             - Datafield1
             - Datafield2
             - Datafield3
             - Datafield4
             - etc etc etc
```

To sort of try and force it to conform to something useable.   But it won't let you do this in Firebase either as it will only fields on documents, not on collections.

So my question is, how can I use this product to cycle through only one users set of data?  I am sure it has to be a simple change to this line:

```
stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').snapshots(),
```

But I can't find anything anywhere online about this.

EDIT:  @SenpaiLeo

Previously I was returning my data like so:

```
return ListView.builder(
  itemExtent: 500,
  itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
      _buildListRows(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
);
```

And then in the _buildListRows:

```
Widget _buildListRows(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
...
  Container(
      child: TextField(
        controller: _storeNameController,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
           border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: document['store_name'],
           ),
        ),
    ),
    ...
```

So it could be now that I have changed the reference based on your recommendation, that now this:

```
document['store_name']
```

Is the incorrect reference?

Comment: what are u getting here stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).snapshots(),
?

Comment: An error that states "Document references must have an even number of segments" which, when I look it up online means that you can't do a snapshots() at all on the document level, you can only do this on the collection level.

Comment: You can do snapshots on document level too. Can you confirm the uid that you are trying to query exists in stores collection.

Comment: Yeah it does mate, and I have set up print captures to show me the UID at various stages in the app, each time it is correct.  The app also pulls data from Firebase successfully, it's just the issue is that it pulls all of the data, rather than the current user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this:

```
Collection:
  - Stores
     Document:
        - UID of user
         Collection:
            - Datafield1
            - Datafield2
            - Datafield3
            - Datafield4
            - etc etc etc
```

And then do:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).snapshots()
```

Then the above should get only the data inside the `uid` document, it wont get the sub collections. If you want to access the data inside the subcollection of one user, then use the following:

```
Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).collection('userStore').snapshots()
```

This will get all the documents inside the subcollection `userStore`

---

Solution:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(currentUserUID).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
       return ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
               _buildListRows(context, snapshot.data),
           );


Widget _buildListRows(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 50, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Business Name',
              style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .body2,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _storeNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: document['store_name'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

This `Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(currentUserUID).snapshots()` will get the document of the current user, then to access it you do `snapshot.data.data["location"]`

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I cannot set up the database like you suggest as it just will not allow it at all.  In Firebase, once you get to the document level the next section is not a collection.   I probably wrote that incorrectly and I will edit it.   It will not allow fields of data on a collection, it will only allow fields of data on a document.   I'll update the question now as I didn't realise this until trying your suggestion.   This is even worse than I thought.

Comment: In firebase you have a collection and inside each collection you have documents and then inside each document you can have subcollections or data for the document

Comment: If you want to get the data for the uid document then u use `document(uid)` to get that. If you have no data inside that document then you won't get anything. If you want to get the data inside the subcollections under that document. Then you do as in the answer. Ex: subcollection `userData` will contain documents that will contain data that you can retrieve.

Comment: Also you can call snapshot on a document check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/54479892/7015400 it's for js but applied on flutter

Comment: When I call .snapshots() on the document level, like this: stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(uid).snapshots(),  I get the following error. 
  "Document references must have an even number of segments".  Google tells me this is because it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Added a screenshot of this simple database in the question, may be easier to see it properly than with my breakdown of the levels.   There really is not much to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213486/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-bisclavret).

Comment: Peter was able to help me with this issue.   Will update answer in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream = Firestore.instance.collection('stores').where('uid', isEqualTo: uid).snapshots();
```

But I would suggest listening to snapshot changes and then updating the variable you need.

Comment: This gets me sort of somewhere!  It doesn't generate any errors at least, so that's something.  It doesn't return any data in my application though.   Previously I was getting data like.. let me update my question to respond to you properly.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted the solution on behalf of the question author in order to move it to the answer space)*.

This is working for me:

```
child: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('stores').document(currentUserUID).snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
       return ListView.builder(
           shrinkWrap: true,
           itemCount: snapshot.data.data.length,
           itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
               _buildListRows(context, snapshot.data),
           );


Widget _buildListRows(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
return Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8,
  child: ListView(
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 50, 0),
            child: Text(
              'Business Name',
              style: Theme
                  .of(context)
                  .textTheme
                  .body2,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 50,
            width: 200,
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 0),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _storeNameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: document['store_name'],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Thanks again to Peter Haddad for his work on this!