# Firestore, onSnapshot() or async/await issue or both

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get an array of changes using Firebase Firestore's [onShapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).

I'm having trouble retrieving data through `onSnapshot()`; I may be in trouble with `async/await` as well, not quite sure...

Can you see where there are problems?

Output should be (but it is currently):

```
1. New friends: ... // via onSnapshot(). Should not be empty, but it is (However, it does get populated afterwards).
2. All friends: ... // Should not be empty, but it is.
3. Fred's friends: ... // Should not be empty, but it is.
```

Code:

```
const getAllFriends = async () => {
    // Gets all friends by connecting to Firestore's onSnapshot stream.

    const getNewFriends = async () => {
        // Sets up a onSnapshot() stream, and returns a newFriends array with their names.
        // Problem: It initially return an empty array, when it shouldn't be empty.

        let newFriends = [];
        await db.collection("user").doc("john").collection("friends").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
                newFriends.push({ friend: "Emily" });
            });
        });

        console.log("1. New friends: ", newFriends, newFriends.length); // Length should not be 0.
        return newFriends;
    }

    // John starts with no friends:
    let friends = []; 

    // John should now have found some friends:
    let friendChanges = await getNewFriends(); 
    friends = friends.concat(friendChanges);

    console.log("2. All friends:", friends); // Should contain a few Emilys.
    return friends;
};

let johnFriends = await getAllFriends();
console.log("3. John's friends:", friends); // Should contain a few Emilys.
```

Comment: If you only need to retrieve data then don't use onSnapshot() function instead use .get() method then async await will might work.

Comment: did you find an answer to this issue? I seem to be having similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54479892/difference-between-get-and-onsnapshot-in-cloud-firestore/54480212#54480212) which explains the difference between the `get()` and `onSnapshot()` methods.

In a nutshell:

- When you use `get()` you retrieve all the documents of the collection **only once** (like a "get and forget").
- When you use `onSnapshot()` you **constantly** listen to the collection.

Note that [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) is not an asynchronous method, while [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#get) is => don't call `onSnapshot()` with `await`.

---

Since, from your question, it seems that you want to get the list of friends by calling the `getAllFriends()` method, do as follows:

```
  const getAllFriends = async (userName) => {
    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('user')
      .doc(userName)
      .collection('friends')
      .get();
    return querySnapshot;
  };

  let johnFriends = await getAllFriends('john');
  johnFriends.forEach(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data());
  });
```

---

More possibilities are to be found in the Firestore doc, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) and [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries).

Comment: Thanks @Renaud, I could use get() but this will only get the data once (?); I'm wanting to set up a listener (thus want to use onSnapshot()). I think I'll have to iterate friendChanges another way...

Comment: Can you please explain what is your exact goal? You can very well set a listener to the `collection("user").doc("john").collection("friends")`collection. But note that if you need to listen to `collection("user").doc("Emily").collection("friends")`, you'll need to set another listener. If you need to listen to ALL the friends documents, you should listen to a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) like `db.collectionGroup('friends')`. Tell me if that is corresponding to your needs, and I'll update the answer.

Comment: This is what should happen: When John logs in, John gets a HTML rendered list of friends using data from `db.collection("user").doc("john").collection("friends")`. When john adds a new friend, his Firestore friends collection gets updated, and so should his HTML rendered list of friends (which is why I think `onSnapshot()` may be the way to go. I suppose I can have a `get()` initially when he logs on, and also have an `onSnapshot()` to listen to later changes; curious to know what you think, thanks!).

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to track newly added John's friends and add them to the `johnFiends` array. Perhaps you can just add the `onsnapshot` listener on top of @Renaud's suggestion:

```
const getAllFriends = async (userName) => {
    const querySnapshot = await db
      .collection('user')
      .doc(userName)
      .collection('friends')
      .get();
    // You may need check for querySnapshot.empty before proceed
    let allFriends = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
    return allFriends;
  };

let johnFriends = await getAllFriends('john');
console.log("All John's friends:", johnFriends);

const unsubscribe = db.collection("user").doc("john").collection("friends")
    .onSnapshot(snapshot => {
        snapshot.docChanges().forEach(change => {
            if (change.type === "added") {
                johnFriends.push(change.doc.data());
                console.log("New John's friend:", change.doc.data());
                console.log("New all John's friends:", johnFriends);
            };
        });
    });
```

Note that `onsnapshot` is mostly for **real-time** tracking of data change at the backend and what you should do later in the frontend, therefore you should apply it on **real-time handler** instead of incorporate it inside a normal data pulling function, e.g. `getAllFriends()`. In short, **handle real-time changes separately**.