# Wait until onSnapshot data is fetched Firestore Firebase Next JS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

On Click I want to fetch onSnapshot instance of data which `startAfter` current data. But When the request is sent for the 1st time it returns an empty array. I have to click twice to get new Data.

```
export default function Page() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [newData, setNewData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [postsEnd, setPostsEnd] = useState(false)
    const [postLimit, setPostLimit] = useState(25)
    const [lastVisible, setLastVisible] = useState(null)


    useEffect(() => {
        const collectionRef = collection(firestore, "Page")
        const queryResult = query(collectionRef, orderBy("CreatedOn", "desc"), limit(postLimit));
        const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(queryResult, (querySnapshot) => {
            setLastVisible(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1])
            setData(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
                CreatedOn : doc.data().CreatedOn?.toDate(),
                UpdatedOn : doc.data().UpdatedOn?.toDate()
                }))
            )
        });
        return unsubscribe;
    }, [postLimit])
    const ths = (
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
        </tr>
    );
    const fetchMore = async () => {
        setLoading(true)
        const collectionRef = collection(firestore, "Page")
        const queryResult = query(collectionRef, orderBy("CreatedOn", "desc"), startAfter(lastVisible), limit(postLimit));
        onSnapshot(await queryResult, (querySnapshot) => {
            setLastVisible(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length-1])
            setNewData(querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                ...doc.data(),
                id: doc.id,
                CreatedOn : doc.data().CreatedOn?.toDate(),
                UpdatedOn : doc.data().UpdatedOn?.toDate()
                }))
            )
        });
        //Commented If Statement cause data is not fetched completely
        //if (newData < postLimit ) { setPostsEnd(true)  }
        setData(data.concat(newData))
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(newData)
    }
    return (
        <>
        <Table highlightOnHover>
          <thead>{ths}</thead>
          <tbody>{
              data.length > 0
              ? data.map((element) => (
                <tr key={element.id}>
                  <td>{element.id}</td>
                  <td>{element.CreatedOn.toString()}</td>
                  <td>{element.UpdatedOn.toString()}</td>
                </tr>
            ))
              : <tr><td>Loading... / No Data to Display</td></tr>
          }</tbody>
        </Table>
        {!postsEnd && !loading ? <Button fullWidth variant="outline" onClick={fetchMore}>Load More</Button> : <></>}
        </>
    )
}
```

*Current Result*
[image: Current Result]

*Expected Result*
[image: Expected Result]

Comment: Are you able to see documents returned from the query by itself when your `useEffect()` initially runs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be rooted in React [updating the state asynchronously](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). I saw the same behavior using your code in my Next.js project. When looking at it closely, the `onSnapshot()` function and your query are working as expected.

You [cannot await `onSnapshot()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521755/) ([code reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_#onsnapshot)) since it's not an asynchronous function, so the async/await in `fetchMore()` does not have any effect. Regardless, React state update is asynchronous, so `setData(data.concat(newData))` might run before `newData` is updated. By the second time you load more documents, `newData` will have the document data.

It looks like `fetchMore()` can be done without relying on a "newData" state, since it was only used to update the actual data and to hide the "Load More" button:

```js
  const fetchMore = () => {
    setLoading(true)
    const collectionRef = collection(firestore, "page")
    const queryResult = query(collectionRef, orderBy("CreatedOn", "desc"), startAfter(lastVisible), limit(postLimit));
    onSnapshot(queryResult, (querySnapshot) => {
      setLastVisible(querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1]);
      //paginatedDocs simply holds the fetched documents
      const paginatedDocs = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
        ...doc.data(),
        id: doc.id,
        CreatedOn: doc.data().CreatedOn?.toDate(),
        UpdatedOn: doc.data().UpdatedOn?.toDate()
      }));
      //Replaced usage of newData here with the amount of documents in paginatedDocs
      if (paginatedDocs.length < postLimit ) { setPostsEnd(true) }
      //Updates the data used in the table directly, rebuilding the component
      setData(data.concat(paginatedDocs));
    });
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

With these changes, there is no problem updating the documents at the first try when clicking the button.

Comment: @Aly did you see more problems with your component state?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have persistence on? It could be firing once with the local result and again with the server data.

Comment: I'm quite a noob. So I'm unable to understand what you are saying can you elaborate a litte?