# Firestore .onSnapshot() await for first query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a wep app with Firebase / Firestore.

At startup, my app waits for settings to be loaded from Firestore.
Then my app is listening for changes from Firestore.

For the first load, I use `.getDoc()` because it returns a promise. I need to be sure data is loaded before moving forward.

For listening continuously, I use `.onSnapshot()`

At startup, my app query twice the database: one for `.getDoc()` and one for `.onSnapshot()`. Indeed, when you call `.onSnapshot()`, the first query is performed instantaneously.

Obviously, I prefer to avoid clients making two identical requests to Firestore. To prevent requesting twice the same data from Firestore, I created a global variable `firstSettingsFromDB` that become true once the callback function of `.onSnapshot()` is called.

Then, in my boot sequence, I created a function that poll my variable `firstSettingsFromDB` until it becomes true, then I can resolve a promise.

```
// Polling until the first settings are fetched from DB
let polling = setInterval(() => {
  // ... check if settings are loaded from DB
  if (this.firstSettingsFromDB) {
    clearInterval(polling);
    resolve();
  }
}, 50)
```

My problem is now that I have the same issue with user data. But user data is not a document, it is a collection. So I need to fetch a collection at startup and being sure the full collection is loaded before moving forward. Then I listen for changes. I can't use polling for my collection since I don't know a priori what the size of the collection is.

Finally, I'm not satisfied by any of these solutions:

- The first one make twice the same query to the database
- The second one use polling, that is not the philosophy of JavaScript
- The second one works only for document, not for collection.

I already read dozen of documentation about this topic, but I can't find a satisfying solution.

- [Firestore, onSnapshot() or async/await issue or both](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64521755/firestore-onsnapshot-or-async-await-issue-or-both)
- https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/iyhn9u/how_can_i_wait_for_the_value_from_onsnapshot_to/
- https://copyprogramming.com/howto/get-a-single-record-document-from-firebase-firestore-using-async-await

I can't figure out how to fetch a collection at startup before mowing forward and then listen for changes properly. I'm beginning to wonder if there isn't a design flaw in the Firestore libraries?

## EDIT

I realized that `.onSnapshot()` queries the full collection at once. However, I still don't like the polling mechanism.

Comment: `onSnapshot()` does not poll.  It opens a listener back to the Firestore server.  The Firestore server monitors the data coming in and out of the database to see if any would impact the query of the listener.  If so, it sends a websocket message to the listener indicating that it needs to re-fetch the query results.  This is a very efficient and scalable approach to "realtime listening".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've noticed, "the first query snapshot contains added events for all existing documents that match the query (or collection)". (Excerpt from the blue background note in this [section of the doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots))

If you want to know when the entire set of documents is loaded for the first time, just trigger an action in the callback function when it is the first time the callback function is called.

For example:

```js
let count = 0;
const q = query(collection(db, "cities"));
const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
  count++;
  if (count === 1) {
    // First load!!
    // Do whatever you want here, e.g. "move forward"
  }
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank You Renault. When I read your answer, it seemed obvious to me. If `count===1` i'll have to trigger an event in `onSnapshot()` that will resolve a promise from another function with something like : `addEventListener('onFirstLoad', () => { resolve() }, {once: true})`.

Comment: You can very well call an asynchronous method/function in the callback function. If you foresee any problem with this specific part, please update your question with the entire code in such a way I can try to further help.

Comment: I understand. First, I prefer not calling asynchronous method in callback functions which can lead to unwanted behaviors. Secondly, my "boot sequence" is more something like 1. Authentification, then 2. Load settings, then 3. Load user data, then 4. ... Since my project is divided into modules, I try to keep them independent of each other.  But thanks to your answer, I'll can write a clean architecture now ! Thx.