# Wait until firebase has finished loading data (vue) / 'await' not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2

In my vue app, I am fetching some data from firebase in the `created`-hook.
I want the code afterwards to be exectuted after the data was finished with loading. But I can not make it work.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>Test 2</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { institutesCollection } from '../firebase';
export default {
    name: 'Test2',
    data() {
        return {
            settings: null,
        }
    },
    async created() {
        await institutesCollection.doc('FbdYJ5FzQ0QVcQEk1KOU').onSnapshot(
            await function(doc) {
                this.settings = doc.data();
                console.log(this.settings);
            }
        )
        console.log('Done with fetching Data');
        console.log(this.settings)
    },
    methods: {
        
    }
}
</script>
```

But one the console, first `'Done with fetching Data'` is displayed, then `null` (because `this.settings` is still `null`) and only after that the Objekt `settings` is printed.
But I need `this.settings` to be defined there (and not `null` anymore) to work with there.

What I tried so far:

1. Putting in awaits
2. Adding a loaded `parameter`
3. Adding the code afterwards in a `then()`

Nothing worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`onSnapshot()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#onsnapshot) method is not an asynchronous method. As explained in the doc, it "attaches a listener for `DocumentSnapshot` events".

So, you should use it if you want to **set a continuous listener** to the Firestore document: if something changes in the document (e.g. a field gets a new value) the listener will be triggered. Note that "an initial call using the callback you provide creates a document snapshot immediately with the current contents of the single document" (see the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)).

You get the Firestore document data only in the callback function that you pass to `onSnapshot()`, as follows:

```
created() {
    institutesCollection.doc('FbdYJ5FzQ0QVcQEk1KOU').onSnapshot(doc => {
           this.settings = doc.data();
           console.log(this.settings);
      });
}
```

As Nilesh Patel mentioned, note that [you need to use an arrow function in order to use `this` in this callback](https://michaelnthiessen.com/this-is-undefined/). Also note that the `created` function **does NOT need to be async**.

Finally, note that it is a good practice to call the unsubscribe function returned by `onSnapshot()` when you destroy the Vue.js component. Use the `beforeDestroy` hook as follows:

```
// ...
data() {
    return {
        settings: null,
        firestoreListener: null
    }
},
created() {
    this.firestoreListener  = institutesCollection.doc('FbdYJ5FzQ0QVcQEk1KOU').onSnapshot(doc => {
           this.settings = doc.data();
           console.log(this.settings);
      });
},
beforeDestroy() {
  if (this.firestoreListener) {
    this.firestoreListener();
  }
},
```

---

On the other hand, if you just want to read the document data **ONLY ONCE** in the created Vue.js hook, you should use the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#get) method, as follows:

```
async created() {
    const doc = await institutesCollection.doc('FbdYJ5FzQ0QVcQEk1KOU').get();
    if (doc.exists) {
             this.settings = doc.data();
    } else {
             // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
             console.log("No such document!");
    }
}
```

Note that, in this case, the `created` function **NEEDS** to be `async`, since `get()` is asynchronous.

---

More details on the difference between `get()` and `onSnapshot()` in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54480212/3371862).

Comment: I was not aware of that! Thank you, that solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

try using arrow function

```
  async created() {
        await institutesCollection.doc('FbdYJ5FzQ0QVcQEk1KOU').onSnapshot(
            doc => {
                this.settings = doc.data();
                console.log(this.settings);
            }
        )
        console.log('Done with fetching Data');
        console.log(this.settings)
  },
```